# How to access a folder in a virtual machine from a computer on the network?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, mdt

I am setting up MDT , where my virtual box VM hosts the server & the deployment share directory.

My client (those which I want to upgrade to Windows 10) need to access the deployment share folder. Clients are across the LAN network .

What changes should i make to enable my client machines to access the folder which is in a virtual machine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the network adapter of the virtual machine to Bridge adapter, it will get an ip from the network and then can be accessed from other computers on that network. (If you are using Virtualbox).

Hope it helps.

Regards.